# Wordpress, iterate child pages on template

Tags: php, wordpress, templates

I have this template to show all the news pages, which all are child pages of the news_all page.
Inside news_all page's template there is the following code.

Part of template get-news-template.php:

```
<?php $the_query = new WP_Query(array(
                      'post_type'      => 'page',
                      'post_parent' => 143
                   ));
    while ($the_query->have_posts())
    {
        $the_query->the_post();
        echo get_the_title();
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

where 143 is the id for news_all page.
For some reason this is not working, am i using this the wrong way? please help.

My final goal is to iterate and show all the news pages as a list in sidebar.

EDIT: added post_type, but still nothing, there is atleast two child pages for this page and they should get echoed, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wordpress has page and post, you must to specify in the query when you want page!

```
$the_query = new WP_Query(array(
                  'post_type'      => 'page',
                  'post_parent' => 143
               ));
```

Comment: are you sure that your page are parent to a page with id 143?
Also you can try to set your news_all as template of page with id 143 and write the query: $current_page_id = get_the_ID();
 $the_query = new WP_Query(array(
                  'post_type'      => 'page',
                  'post_parent' => $current_page_id
               ));

Comment: News all id = 143, and i want childeren of that page to show up, this template is for parent pages, which should iterate and show all the child pages.

Comment: hmm, i didnt do anything but was getting food, and meantime this script started working. Cheers!